# How to pass secret information to ecs docker flags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I want to pass a password directory path to docker flag the docker image is a third party image So, I can't make any kind of change in that container.
Here is the flag I use in AWS ECS --wallet-password-file=/path/to/.txt_file
I have seen the aws secret storing service https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-tutorial.html here but I am a bit confused about to pass password directory to the ECS task definition.
The password is written in simple text file and I just add path of that directory in flag.

Can anyone please suggest anything to hide the password file/password and correct way to pass it on that flag without revealing it to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If the image does not support configuration via environment variables (for example something like `WALLET_PASSWORD_FILE` you still have the option to override the entry point of the image. The advantage of this is that you don't actually have to build your own image.

Simply override the entry point with a script that takes your config as an env variable and then pass it on to the script that actually starts whatever process is supposed to run in the respective image.